# Categorizing HTML Select

Tags: html, vue.js

Hey everyone,
             I'd like to know whether it's possible to categorize an HTML dropdown list using the provided options' first letters.
        Example, i'm generating a dropdown purely from database and i can't predict what the options will be in the v-for loop in html. So, is it possible.??
And i'm using the vue.js framework and i'm already aware of the tree feature, but i don't want to use the tree feature, i'm looking for a way which can only include HTML.

Code:-

```
<div class="col-xl-7">
    <select size="sm" class="form-control m-input m-input--air" v-model="programDetailID">
        <option v-if="checkProg==true" v-for="program in modelProgram" :value="program.programDetailID">
            {{program.description}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Any and All help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank You.!

Comment: Please share an example of the code you are having problems with like the dropdown component and the bindings.

Comment: I'll edit it in the question

Comment: yes its possible with `optgroup` as array and `option` as arrays's child, there will be two for loop in vuejs

Comment: I tried using optgroup but it kept repeating the whole dropdown again and again...i know i'm doing something wrong with optgroup but i just can't see it

Comment: @OmerKhan you should post what you had tried with the `optgroup` and what did not work out. You are more likely to get help that way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `optgroup` as suggested and have it look like this.

Assuming you have a  `category` level to you model

```
<div class="col-xl-7">
 <select size="sm" class="form-control m-input m-input--air" v-model="programDetailID">
  <!-- Add a category for loop here -->
  <optgroup v-for="category in categories" :label="category.name">
   <option v-if="checkProg==true" v-for="program in category.modelProgram" :value="program.programDetailID">{{program.description}}</option>
  </optgroup>
 </select>
```